# List of 'most popular' posts (based on # of views)

Tags: wordpress, sorting, thumbnails, categories

I'd like to show a list of **most popular** posts sorted by **number of views**.

I'd like to show small thumbnails (the same image(s) used in the posts just resized to fit) on left, and excerpt on right. So the formatting would look like:

```
[#1 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

[#2 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

[#3 Post Title]
[80x80 thumbnail] [excerpt, limit to x chars]

... up to 5 posts
```

Is there a plugin available for this? If can be achieved by simply using wordpress template tags, I'd prefer that over a 3rd party plugin. But important to me is display formatting, I need thumbnails on left.

Comment: Why? isn't it 'programming related'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [plugin](http://polpoinodroidi.com/wordpress-plugins/wordpresscom-popular-posts/) that works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a plugin like [Wordpress popular posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/). 
This plugin can't do exactly what you want, but it records pageviews in the database, and you can use that data in your theme by writing code like the following:

```
$right_now = gmdate("Y-m-d");

$max_most_read = 5; // Number of "most read-spots" 

$qstr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
    (select postid, sum(pageviews) pageviews 
     from $pageviews_table 
     where day >= '$right_now' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
     group by postid) pv
    WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.ID = pv.postid
    AND wposts.post_date >= '$right_now' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    ORDER BY pv.pageviews DESC
    LIMIT 0, " . $max_most_read . "
 ";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($qstr);
if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
        $category = get_the_category();

        # Now you can use $post->post_content to extract image tag and excerpt
        # See http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-get-the-first-image-from-the-post-and-display-it
        # on how to extract and resize first image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to avoid a third party plugin as much as possible than this might help. It does require a plug-in - **[wp-postiews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/)** - but only to store the number of page views. Once you've done that you can use the code below to fully customise what you display and how you sort it. I have used it for much the same purpose as you are ([I wanted to display the thumbnails of the most popular posts in a thumbnail slider](http://www.harriswebsolutions.co.uk/blog/2011/jquery-thumbnail-slider-sorting-popular-posts-%E2%80%93-part-2/)).

Now, lets say you wanted to display your posts as a list:

```
    <ul>
      <?php echo get_popular_thumb(5); ?>
    </ul>
```

Where the function `popularPostsThumb()` will be defined below (and you can alter how many posts you want displayed), but will return the content of the list elements, inside the list tags `<li></li>`.

Now define the above function in your `functions.php` file

```
function get_popular_thumb($limit=10) {
    global $wpdb;
    $most_viewed = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.*, (meta_value+0)  AS views FROM $wpdb->posts LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID WHERE post_type='post' AND post_date < '".current_time('mysql')."' AND post_status = 'publish' AND meta_key = 'views' AND post_password = '' ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT $limit");

    if($most_viewed) {
        foreach ($most_viewed as $post) {
            $id = $post->ID;
            $post_views = intval($post->views);
            $post_title = get_the_title($post);
            $post_title = $post->post_title;
            $related_thumbnail = get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumbnail_url", $single = true);
            $thumb_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id ( $post->ID ));

        if (has_post_thumbnail($id )){
            $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($id) . '" title="'. $post_title . '"><img src="'. $thumb_src[0].'" title="'. $post_title .'"/>  </a> </li>';
        }
    }
}
return $output;}
```

In this example it just outputs the thumbnail of the image - but inside the `<li></li>` tags you can change the HTML to produce what you wanted (plus a some CSS styling). You can easily extract the excerpt of the post - I've not tested it, but something like `$excerpt= $post->post_excerpt` should work.(There are 'neater' ways of getting the thumbnail of the post - but this way you can manually edit the title of the `<img>`).

Hope this helps.